# What is the effect of adding [0] at the end of document.getElementsByTagName(input)[0]

Tags: javascript, dom

I see some code which makes use of a [0] at the end of `document.getElementsByTagName(input)[0]` and I have no ideas what that does or what it means.  I tried looking for it on w3schools and found them using it , but no explanations as to why.

Would some kind soul please help me understand what this suffix implies.  How do these two commands differ...

```
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName)?

Comment: @Jon: I read it.  It doesn't say anything about `[0]`.

Comment: Arrgh!  It is a collection.  So, it must be the first element.  W3schools puts it this way..."The getElementsByTagName() method accesses all elements with the specified tagname." So it does not sound like a collection.  And this statement is true for `getElementById("abc")` too... I feel like a nut job...  Thanks!

Comment: @DeKoss Note that `document.getElementById()` returns the first found element with that `id` (or `null`, if nothing found).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but I know that.  Nevertheless, if you read the W3Schools.com explanation it can be true for the '...ById' version too.  They should have said, ."The getElementsByTagName() method accesses all elements with the specified tagname AT ONCE in a collection."  'byId' accesses all the same named ID elements to, but one at a time.  See the problem?

Comment: @DeKoss — `byId` returns either `null` or an HTMLElement object. You can't have multiple elements with the same id in a document, so "one at a time" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank heavens for jQuery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `getElementsByTagName` returns a **list** of elements, so with `[0]` you are accessing the first element of that list.

Comment: King   It makes perfect sense.  Thank you for the kind reply. W3Scool.com needs to reword their explanation.  I guess that they assume that we can figure it out by the fact that there may be multiple 'Input' elements  The problem is that I have seen it used as follows:  `u=getElementByTagname('body')[0]` and I did not see how that could be a collection...

Comment: @DeKoss W3Schools needs to reword a lot of explanations. Stick to MDN's docs

Comment: I will take your advice.  I never knew about MDN.  Great discovery!

Answer (score 3):

`[0]` means the same here that it means in practically every other JavaScript context: *Get the value of the property with the name `0`*.

`getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList, which is like an Array. `[0]` gets the first item from it.

Comment: These two sentences seem contradictory.  The second sentence seems like it's correct.  Wouldn't "by name" imply quotation marks?

Comment: Obviously...  But W3Schools gives a funky explanations which does not make it appear as a collection...  Thanx for the clarification...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Not really. Every property name of a JavaScript object is a string anyway. `0` or `"0"` happens to be the name of that property.

Comment: @DeKoss: That's why w3Schools is bad and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) is better

Comment: So, what does this mean, `getElementByTagname('body')[0]` since this is a collection.  Are there some hidden bodies in a typical HTML file?  Or is it the first object in the body, which is an improper way of using a collection command?

Comment: @DeKoss `getElementsByTagName` **always** returns a **collection** (array). It doesn't magically return something different if there's only one found. To get the first, only, or nth item, you have to use `[]` (or technically `.getItem()`). To get the body, you can use `document.body` just as easily

Comment: @DeKoss — It means get the fist element with the TagName 'body'. The fact that (in a valid HTML document) there can only be one element with that tag name is beside the point. The interface is consistent, it always returns a NodeList. That NodeList can contain zero, one or any other number of elements.

Comment: @RobertHarvey — The property name gets stringified. So `0` gets converted to `"0"`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but people using `getElementByTagname('body')[0]` should be whipped for referring to the body element when they can use Document.body!

Answer (score 1):

This is index of element, if you have more tags then every tag have index.

```
<div></div> //index 0
<div></div> //index 1
```

Comment: So what does this mean, then...  `getElementByTagname('body')[0]`?  There is only one body, yet I have seen this code line in DataTables.js frequently...

Comment: @DeKoss—because *getElementsByTagName* **always** returns a NodeList, even if there are no matching elements (in which case it will be an empty list and have a length of 0).

Comment: At least now I know that `getElementByTagname('body')[0]` is equivalent to `document.body`.  But some people do not want to call a bicycle by name, so they call it "Butt support on wheels".  Are we on the same wavelength now?